# Maui - How to create a circle button using xaml style

Tags: xaml, maui

I want to make a xaml style for a circle button.
A circle button would have equal width and height, and a corner radius of half the width. I would like to have a style where I only need to set one property, like the WidthRequest, and the other properties are calculated based on the property I set.
So ideally I could have

```
<Button WidthRequest="120"
        Style="{StaticResource Circle}"/>
```

So the height and width would reference each other, and the corner radius would use the math converter to half the width. Something like

```
<Style x:Key="Square"
           TargetType="View">
        <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="{Binding HeightRequest, Source={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="{Binding WidthRequest, Source={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="Circle"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource Square}"
           TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{Binding WidthRequest, Source={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource toolkit:MathExpressionConverter}, ConverterParameter='x/2'}"/>
    </Style>
```

However, The self reference in the style sheet references the Setter, instead of the control that consumes the style.

#### Work Around

*As a work around I have a CircleButton control, below. This works but I'd prefer to use a style instead of a custom control*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Button xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App.CircleButton"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             WidthRequest="{Binding HeightRequest, Source={RelativeSource Self}}"
             HeightRequest="{Binding WidthRequest, Source={RelativeSource Self}}"
             CornerRadius="{Binding WidthRequest, Source={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource MathExpressionConverter}, ConverterParameter='x/2'}">
    <Button.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <toolkit:MathExpressionConverter x:Key="MathExpressionConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's better to create your own button by using other controls. Check the below code, it displays a circle button without actual using the control button.

```
        <Grid>

            <Ellipse 
                 StrokeThickness="3"
                 WidthRequest="70"
                 HeightRequest="70"/>

            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                  <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TakePhotoGestureRecognizer_Tapped"
                                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        </Grid>
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Thank you for the response, but as I show in my example work around, I can create a button in a control. I'm looking to style the button in xaml style instead, so your answer is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

> So the height and width would reference each other, and the corner radius would use the math converter to half the width.

You can check the doc [Button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/button?view=net-maui-7.0):  `CornerRadius`, of type `int`, describes the corner radius of the button's border. So no matter how much the height and width is, just set `CornerRadius` to 50:

```xml
        <Button Text="CLICK"
                WidthRequest="65"
                HeightRequest="65"
                CornerRadius="50"/>
```

Here is the [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2Ina.png).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I appreciate the work around, but this only works if the width is 100. Anything lower and you get a diamond shape. Anything higher and you have a rounded square

Comment: ? Sorry, I still don't quite understand what you mean. I mean if you just want a circle button, to set the same value of `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest`, and `CornerRadius` keeps 50.

Comment: I implemented the code you recommended, with a corner radius of 50, but with various width/heights. If the width/height is less than 100, the shape is a diamond. If the width/height is more than 100, the shape is a rounded square. I am looking for a styling where I only need to set the width, and the height and corner radius will be calculated from that.

Comment: As Sun said that you must keep `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` same e.g. 65 65.  If they are not same, you cannot get a perfect circle button.